# JavaFX pulse logger giving excessive "slow background path for null"

Tags: java, javafx

When enabling the JavaFX pulse logger in my application, I am seeing an excessive amount of "slow background path for null" errors. The resulting counters do not look too bad, but the renderBackgrounds slow paths does also seem excessively high:

```
Counters:
    NGRegion renderBackgroundShape slow path: 8
    NGRegion renderBackgrounds slow path: 204
    Nodes rendered: 1251
    Nodes visited during render: 1279
```

I am mainly wondering what could be influencing such high slow paths, and how I can better debug what is causing it to be such.

I have not tried anything specific, the goal was to try to optimize my program as I noticed the CPU was consistently spiking past 20% after switching tabs and scrolling through list views often.

Comment: If I am in your position, I would rather start with analyzing the performance with any profiling tool to first understand what actually causing this.

Comment: @SaiDandem java profiling tools do not show native CPU usages such as those used by JavaFX. There's also the question of what does null in "slow background path for null" refer to?

Comment: @BayanR *There's also the question of what does null in "slow background path for null" refer to?* -> who knows? does it even matter? what does "slow paths does also seem excessively high" mean?  Does it have anything to do with "CPU was consistently spiking past 20% "? (not me for any of those questions).  The pulse logger is neither a documented nor a supported thing, I guess one could consult the source code or ask the openjfx-dev mailing list for info, it wouldn't be my first choice in trying to find out what the performance bottleneck is.

Comment: @jewelsea it does matter. 204 slow paths is quite unusually high compared to other JavaFX programs. Typically, nulls in logs aren't a good indicator.

Comment: @BayanR interesting to know, thx for the info BayanR.

Comment: I agree with Sai, grab a Java profiler, and profile the thing to see where it may be spending time.  As BayanR notes, it isn't going to help with native code which JavaFX is executing on the CPU and GPU.  The vast majority of JavaFX code (both in the framework and in your app), is plain Java.  If the profiling doesn't turn up something and the issue isn't with your app code, then you will likely need expert help to resolve your issue (probably from a core JavaFX developer), of the kind that I don't think you would find on StackOverflow, unless you are lucky.